# Migrating from local GitLab to cloud based GitLab results in npm test failing: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined"

Tags: npm, jestjs, gitlab, puppeteer

On our local build instance with GitLab running jest everything works fine. We are migrating everything to gitlab's cloud and running ci/cd there. The linter, build, etc. all work, but when it gets to npm test and tries to execute the tests, every one of them fails with the same error in same place:

```
FAIL tests/Charts.test.js 
 ● Test suite failed to run
TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined
  42 | 
  43 | afterAll(() => {
> 44 |  browser.close();
     |          ^
  45 | });
```

Feels like a dependency issue or configuration. Any help would be appreciated. LMK if something else is needed like package file.

Comment: Can you share your (redacted) `.gitlab-ci.yml` file?

Comment: added the gitlab-ci.yml as requested. Not much there...

Comment: Are you using your own runners? If so, are they using the `shell` or `docker` executor (or something else)? If using Gitlab's own shared runners, what image are you using for your builds?

Answer (score 0):

We figured out the problem, turns out the xserver stuff wasn't installed and since we had headless set to false, the browser window couldn't open up.

Setting 'headless' to 'true' let us progress